# getter/state are not calling on initial time vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to return a function into computed property but on page refresh getter or state does not load the data into computed property. How can I resolve this ? I did try async await into computed property too it doesn't work. Please guide.

```
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            isLoading: false,
        }
    },
    async created(){
        await this.profile()
    },
    methods: {
        async profile(){
            this.isLoading = true;
            return await Promise.all([
                this.$store.dispatch('class'),
                this.$store.dispatch('list')
            ]).finally(() => {
                this.isLoading = false;
            })
        }
    },
    computed: {
        getItem() {
            console.log(this.$store.getters); //This records did not load at first time after rerouting it does work
            return () => this.$store.getters.listItem;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not do async things in lifecycle hooks if you need them to be completed at the time when a comp is rendered. If this involves a router, do this in router hook instead

Comment: What is the best way to fix this ? can you re-write this please ?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71349355/is-it-possible-to-use-the-beforeenter-navigation-guard-in-vue-router-to-redirect . Check router hook docs

Comment: Why do you need to return a function? You can use `mapGetters` and take advantage of reactivity `computed: { ...mapGetters(['listItem']) }`? Then use it anywhere as `this.listItem` (e.g: `<pre v-if="listItem" v-text="JSON.stringify(listItem, null, 2)" />`). Consider providing more detail on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why you need to return a function from the computed value.
However, using the computed value in your template will work.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ getItem() }}
  </div>
</template>
```

But if you want to see your console log, you can use a local variable to force the Vue to watch changes.

```js
computed: {
  getItem() {
    const lst = this.$store.getters.listItem;
    console.log(lst);
    return () => lst;
  },
},
```

I think it is better to use the store value directly.

```js
computed: {
  getItem() {
    return this.$store.getters.listItem;
  },
},
```

Comment: A shorter form would be `computed: { ...mapGetters({ getItem: "listItem" }) }`. But I'd argue `getItem` is not a very good name for a computed. `item` or `listItem` would be more appropriate, IMHO.